# Highlight a specific cell based on the criteria in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I have a data table and I would like to highlight the cells when the value is in between the slider range. `red` if the value is between `100 - 75`, `yellow` if it is btw  `75 - 50`, and `green` if it is btw  `< 50`. How to get around this? Many thanks in advance.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)  # for the diamonds dataset

diamonds <- diamonds[,c("carat", "depth", "table", "price", "x", "y","z" )]

ui <- fluidPage(
  title = "Examples of DataTables",
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      conditionalPanel(
        'input.dataset === "diamonds"',
        checkboxGroupInput("show_vars", "Columns in diamonds to show:",
                           names(diamonds), selected = names(diamonds)),
        
        sliderInput("slider2", label = h3("Slider Range"), min = 0, max = 100, 
                    value = c(25, 75))
      )
  
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        id = 'dataset',
        tabPanel("diamonds", DT::dataTableOutput("mytable1"))
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # choose columns to display
  diamonds2 = diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ]
  output$mytable1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(diamonds2[, input$show_vars, drop = FALSE])
  })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `formatStyle` and `styleInterval` and make dependent on your inputs.

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # choose columns to display
  diamonds2 = diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ]
  
  output$mytable1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    formatStyle(datatable(diamonds2[, input$show_vars, drop = FALSE]), 
                input$show_vars,
                backgroundColor = styleInterval(c(input$slider2[1], input$slider2[2]), 
                                                c('green', 'yellow', 'red')))
  })
  
}
```